# Swipe left/right for next image URL in the array in a Cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a album id and photo urls inside that id. So I am trying to present a photo gallery swipe next and forth like instagram multiple photos post. There are some related questions but none of them worked for me because im working in a cell, and I couldn't figure out how to download each image for each swipe right action. I also couldn't decide whether I should use swipe gesture or add a scroll view horizontally. I also need to add a like button. I have done my search but swiping in a cell is always considered as swiping the row.

Here is my code for tableview

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return actors.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ActorCell") as? ActorCell else {return UITableViewCell() }

    cell.nameLbl.text = actors[indexPath.row].uploaderUsername
    cell.dateLbl.text = actors[indexPath.row].uploadTime

    let myStringArray = actors[indexPath.row].photoURLS.components(separatedBy: ", ")
    let finalUrlString = "http://demoweb.com\(myStringArray[counter])"


    let url = URL(string: finalUrlString)
    let processor = DownsamplingImageProcessor(size: cell.imgView.bounds.size)
        |> RoundCornerImageProcessor(cornerRadius: 20)
    cell.imgView.kf.indicatorType = .activity

    cell.imgView.kf.setImage(
        with: url,
        placeholder: UIImage(named: "91"),
        options: [
            .processor(processor),
            .scaleFactor(UIScreen.main.scale),
            .transition(.fade(1)),
            .cacheOriginalImage
        ])
    {
        result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let value):
            print("Task done for: \(value.source.url?.absoluteString ?? "")")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Job failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

and cell's control view

```
@IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!
@IBOutlet var imgView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nameLbl: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

@IBAction func swiperightt(_ sender: Any) {
    counter -= 0
    print(counter)

}
@IBAction func swipeleftt(_ sender: Any) {
    counter += 1
    print(counter)

}
```

it doesn't even print out the counter so it doesn't read the swipe I guess. I tried to do the same on the main view controller but didn't work because I don't know how to re run the download code so it can reach the other url

Edit for the comment: swiperightt and leftt are gestures not buttons

Thanks...

Comment: swiperightt / swipeleftt is action from button ? Or it's a gesture you add to TableView ?

Comment: It’s a gesture sir

Comment: you need integrate gesture in your tableview, not your tableviewcell.

Comment: Is there any solutions you could provide? I really need some help here.

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is to show next or previous image on left and right scroll then
i suggest to use collection view inside tableview cell, it will be easy for you. You can use paging to display one image at a time. And collection will manage left and right scroll itself.